# batch - filter folders by name with "@" at beginning

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, filter, pattern-matching, directory

I do have folder with folders

```
my_folders
    @folder1
    @next_one
    some_folder_without_at
    @third
    some_file.txt
```

I got so far adding all folders

```
for /d %%i in ("C:\my\path\to\my_folders\*") do (
    call :setfolders %%i
)
```

Goal: I want to filter result and add **only folders with @ at beginning**

Comment: Tag says `bash` but script looks like Windows/DOS batch file ?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about bash? Doesn't look like it to me. Have you tried `@*` at the end of that pattern?

Comment: If `bash` use a glob `@*`

Comment: Under *nix this is very easy... `find /path/my_folders -type d -name @\* -print`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to process files in the `my_folders` directory that begin with `@`, the wildcard is quite simple:

```
for i in my_folders/@*;
do
    setfolders "$i"
done
```

If you want to only process those that are directories themselves, you have a choice of adding `/` to the wildcard, or testing the type within the loop:

```
for i in my_folders/@*/;
do
    setfolders "${i%/}"
done
```

```
for i in my_folders/@*;
do
    test -d "$i" && setfolders "$i"
done
```